# Broken javascript "display: none" combined with some SVG. Not sure where to start

Tags: javascript, html, svg

I am having some trouble on a coding project and my js skills are a bit rusty.   I am stuck and could use some help.

I am building an html page that I have embedded an svg into that I have exported from Illustrator.   I am using JS to make the image disappear when clicked, and reappear when clicked again.

My problem is that I click the hexagon generated by the SVG/HTML below and everything disappears, and I can't get anything to reappear.  Ideally clicking where the blue hexagon was would re-show everything.

I'd like to keep the Javascript the same as I am using it for other parts of the graphic and everything else is working perfectly.  I imagine I need to change something in my HTML.

Here is the Javascript I am using:

```
function changeItem(element){
    var element  = document.getElementById(element).children;

    if(element[0].style.display == 'none'){
        for (var i = 0; i < element.length - 1; i++) {
             element[i].style.display = ''
  }
    }else{
        for (var i = 0; i < element.length - 1; i++) {
    element[i].style.display = 'none'
  }
    }
}
```

The HTML is a bit longer -- so sorry for outside link:  https://pastebin.com/i7tA9Sbz.
The javascript function is called on line 256.

Any thoughts on how I can change the html to get this working correctly?

Really appreciate your help!

Answer (score 1):

Setting the display to none means that the elements are no longer rendered so there's nothing to receive mouse events.

Instead you want to use the [visibility property](https://svgwg.org/svg2-draft/render.html#VisibilityControl) to hide the elements and the [pointer-events property](https://svgwg.org/svg2-draft/interact.html#PointerEventsProperty) to ensure that hidden elements still receive mouse events. That's more efficient than using the opacity property as a pseudo hiding mechanism.

```js
function changeItem(element){
    var element  = document.getElementById(element).children;

    if(element[0].style.visibility == 'hidden'){
        for (var i = 0; i < element.length - 1; i++) {
             element[i].style.visibility = 'visible'
  }
    }else{
        for (var i = 0; i < element.length - 1; i++) {
    element[i].style.visibility = 'hidden'
  }
    }
}
```

```css
.cls-1 {
        isolation: isolate;
      }
      .cls-2 {
        fill: #3ab694;
      }

      .cls-3 {
        font-size: 22.22px;
      }

      .cls-10, .cls-3 {
        fill: blue;
      }

      .cls-3, .cls-35, .cls-42 {
        font-family: Grold-Medium, Grold;
        font-weight: 500;
      }

      .cls-4 {
        letter-spacing: -0.01em;
      }

      .cls-5 {
        letter-spacing: 0em;
      }

      .cls-6 {
        letter-spacing: -0.07em;
      }

      .cls-7 {
        letter-spacing: -0.01em;
      }

      .cls-8 {
        letter-spacing: -0.01em;
      }

      .cls-9 {
        fill: #62c08c;
      }

      .cls-15, .cls-29, .cls-33, .cls-9 {
        opacity: 0.5;
      }

      .cls-15, .cls-20, .cls-26, .cls-29, .cls-33, .cls-9 {
        mix-blend-mode: multiply;
      }

      .cls-11, .cls-16, .cls-21, .cls-27, .cls-30, .cls-34 {
        opacity: 0.15;
        mix-blend-mode: overlay;
      }

      .cls-11 {
        fill: url(#White_Black_2);
      }

      .cls-12 {
        fill: #0bb1d2;
      }

      .cls-13 {
        letter-spacing: -0.01em;
      }

      .cls-14 {
        letter-spacing: -0.03em;
      }

      .cls-15 {
        fill: #2fb2cb;
      }

      .cls-16 {
        fill: url(#White_Black_2-2);
      }

      .cls-17 {
        fill: #223f70;
      }

      .cls-18 {
        letter-spacing: -0.01em;
      }

      .cls-19 {
        letter-spacing: -0.02em;
      }

      .cls-20 {
        fill: #0d70a6;
      }

      .cls-20, .cls-26 {
        opacity: 0.45;
      }

      .cls-21 {
        fill: url(#White_Black_2-3);
      }

      .cls-22 {
        fill: #226869;
      }
      .cls-23 {
        letter-spacing: -0.02em;
      }

      .cls-24 {
        letter-spacing: 0em;
      }

      .cls-25 {
        letter-spacing: -0.01em;
      }

      .cls-26 {
        fill: #ac2752;
      }

      .cls-27 {
        fill: url(#White_Black_2-4);
      }

      .cls-28 {
        fill: #eca825;
      }

      .cls-29 {
        fill: #e8584b;
      }

      .cls-30 {
        fill: url(#White_Black_2-5);
      }

      .cls-31 {
        fill: #543a71;
      }

      .cls-32 {
        letter-spacing: -0.03em;
      }

      .cls-33 {
        fill: #fec24e;
      }

      .cls-34 {
        fill: url(#White_Black_2-6);
      }

      .cls-35 {
        font-size: 36.1px;
      }

      .cls-35, .cls-42 {
        fill: #231f20;
      }

      .cls-36 {
        letter-spacing: -0.05em;
      }

      .cls-37 {
        letter-spacing: -0.09em;
      }

      .cls-38 {
        letter-spacing: -0.1em;
      }

      .cls-39 {
        letter-spacing: -0.02em;
      }

      .cls-40 {
        letter-spacing: -0.01em;
      }

      .cls-41 {
        fill: #100b0b;
      }

      .cls-42 {
        font-size: 16.66px;
      }

      .cls-43 {
        letter-spacing: -0.01em;
      }

      .cls-44 {
        letter-spacing: -0.01em;
      }

      .cls-45 {
        letter-spacing: -0.01em;
      }

      .cls-46 {
        letter-spacing: 0em;
      }

      .cls-47 {
        letter-spacing: 0.02em;
      }

      .cls-48 {
        letter-spacing: -0.02em;
      }

      .cls-49 {
        letter-spacing: 0em;
      }

      .cls-50 {
        letter-spacing: 0em;
      }

      .cls-51 {
        letter-spacing: 0.02em;
      }
```

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" 
     xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"  
     width="960px" 
     height="560px" 
     viewBox="0 0 960px 560px">
 <defs>

      <linearGradient id="White_Black_2" data-name="White, Black 2" x1="303.54" y1="51.04" x2="476.73" y2="224.23" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
        <stop offset="0" stop-color="#fff"/>
        <stop offset="1" stop-color="#010101"/>
      </linearGradient>
      <linearGradient id="White_Black_2-2" x1="108.25" y1="250.7" x2="381.22" y2="523.68" xlink:href="#White_Black_2"/>
      <linearGradient id="White_Black_2-3" x1="250.27" y1="417.78" x2="496.01" y2="663.52" xlink:href="#White_Black_2"/>
      <linearGradient id="White_Black_2-4" x1="508.24" y1="517.37" x2="681.43" y2="690.55" xlink:href="#White_Black_2"/>
      <linearGradient id="White_Black_2-5" x1="603.75" y1="217.92" x2="876.72" y2="490.89" xlink:href="#White_Black_2"/>
      <linearGradient id="White_Black_2-6" x1="488.96" y1="78.08" x2="734.7" y2="323.82" xlink:href="#White_Black_2"/>
    </defs>
 <g id="Middle_Info" onclick="changeItem('Middle_Info')" data-name="Middle Info" pointer-events="all">
      <polygon class="cls-10" points="438.48 490.62 285.48 492.54 207.32 360.99 282.17 227.53 435.17 225.62 513.32 357.17 438.48 490.62"/>
      <text class="cls-35" transform="translate(223.6 362.5)">INN<tspan class="cls-36" x="54.62" y="0">O</tspan><tspan class="cls-37" x="78.88" y="0">V</tspan><tspan class="cls-38" x="97.73" y="0">A</tspan><tspan x="116.21" y="0">TION </tspan><tspan class="cls-39" x="200.62" y="0">3</tspan><tspan class="cls-40" x="217.73" y="0">6</tspan><tspan x="235.99" y="0">0°</tspan></text>
      <g>
        <path class="cls-41" d="M387.46,318.38h1.3v-11h-1.3Zm11.88-2.85-7.9-8.63v11.48h1.3V310.1l7.9,8.7V307.38h-1.3Zm12.8-6.53a5.91,5.91,0,0,0-1.82-1.19,5.84,5.84,0,0,0-2.21-.43h-3.56a1.77,1.77,0,0,1-.57-.1,1.5,1.5,0,0,1-.38-.19l-.11-.08-.93.86.13.12a2.23,2.23,0,0,0,.56.36,3.91,3.91,0,0,0,.58.19,2.79,2.79,0,0,0,.48.09h.07v0h1.3v0h2.43a4.46,4.46,0,0,1,1.71.34,4.57,4.57,0,0,1,1.4.91,4.33,4.33,0,0,1,.95,1.36,4,4,0,0,1,0,3.29,4.25,4.25,0,0,1-.95,1.34,4.57,4.57,0,0,1-1.4.91,4.45,4.45,0,0,1-1.71.33h-2.43v-7.25h-1.3v8.51h3.73a5.84,5.84,0,0,0,2.21-.43,6.07,6.07,0,0,0,1.82-1.18,5.66,5.66,0,0,0,1.23-1.74,5.2,5.2,0,0,0,.45-2.14,5.13,5.13,0,0,0-.45-2.14A5.59,5.59,0,0,0,412.14,309Zm6,3.53H424v-1.26h-5.92v-2.63H425v-1.26h-8.16v3.88a2.09,2.09,0,0,1-.41-.09A1.42,1.42,0,0,1,416,311l-.11-.09-.94.86.14.12a2,2,0,0,0,.56.37,3.91,3.91,0,0,0,.58.19,2.65,2.65,0,0,0,.48.08h.07v5.86h8.29v-1.26h-7Zm16.9-4.61a3.7,3.7,0,0,0-1.1-.42,6.23,6.23,0,0,0-1.22-.12h-5v11H429V312.5h3.78a5.91,5.91,0,0,0,1.59-.19,2.77,2.77,0,0,0,1-.55,2,2,0,0,0,.58-.83,2.83,2.83,0,0,0,.17-1,2.39,2.39,0,0,0-.31-1.25A2.45,2.45,0,0,0,435,307.92Zm-.32,2.72a.8.8,0,0,1-.37.38,1.85,1.85,0,0,1-.65.19,6.41,6.41,0,0,1-.93.06H429v-2.63h3.72a3.47,3.47,0,0,1,1.67.3,1.05,1.05,0,0,1,.47,1A1.46,1.46,0,0,1,434.7,310.64Zm5.08,1.89h5.92v-1.26h-5.92v-2.63h6.86v-1.26h-8.16v3.88a2,2,0,0,1-.4-.09,1.5,1.5,0,0,1-.38-.19l-.1-.09-.94.86.13.12a1.93,1.93,0,0,0,.57.37,3.56,3.56,0,0,0,.58.19,2.43,2.43,0,0,0,.47.08h.07v5.86h8.3v-1.26h-7Zm16.42,3-7.9-8.63v11.48h1.3V310.1l7.9,8.7V307.38h-1.3ZM469,309a5.91,5.91,0,0,0-1.82-1.19,5.84,5.84,0,0,0-2.21-.43h-3.56a1.77,1.77,0,0,1-.57-.1,1.35,1.35,0,0,1-.38-.19l-.11-.08-.94.86.14.12a2.23,2.23,0,0,0,.56.36,3.91,3.91,0,0,0,.58.19,2.79,2.79,0,0,0,.48.09h.07v0h1.3v0H465a4.5,4.5,0,0,1,1.71.34,4.57,4.57,0,0,1,1.4.91,4.33,4.33,0,0,1,.95,1.36,4,4,0,0,1,0,3.29,4.25,4.25,0,0,1-.95,1.34,4.57,4.57,0,0,1-1.4.91,4.45,4.45,0,0,1-1.71.33h-2.43v-7.25h-1.3v8.51H465a5.84,5.84,0,0,0,2.21-.43,5.9,5.9,0,0,0,1.81-1.18,5.35,5.35,0,0,0,1.23-1.74,5.21,5.21,0,0,0,.46-2.14,5.14,5.14,0,0,0-.46-2.14A5.41,5.41,0,0,0,469,309Zm6,3.53h5.91v-1.26H475v-2.63h6.86v-1.26h-8.16v3.88a2.09,2.09,0,0,1-.41-.09,1.42,1.42,0,0,1-.37-.19l-.11-.09-.94.86.13.12a1.93,1.93,0,0,0,.57.37,3.91,3.91,0,0,0,.58.19,2.65,2.65,0,0,0,.48.08h.07v5.86H482v-1.26h-7Zm16.41,3-7.9-8.63v11.48h1.3V310.1l7.9,8.7V307.38h-1.3Zm3.15-6.89h4v9.74h1.3v-9.74h3.94v-1.26h-9.2Zm28.7-1.26-4.34,8.24-4.29-8.15-.05-.09h-1.44l5.78,11.23,5.76-11.23Zm3.31,3.86a1.5,1.5,0,0,1-.45-.09,1.23,1.23,0,0,1-.38-.19l-.11-.08-.93.85.12.12a2,2,0,0,0,.7.44c.16,0,.31.1.45.13l-3.08,6h1.51l3-5.86H530l2.87,5.77,0,.09h1.46l-5.73-11.23Zm2.89,0H528l.74-1.47Zm14.75,1a2.17,2.17,0,0,0,.72-.61,2.34,2.34,0,0,0,.39-.81,3.26,3.26,0,0,0,.12-.87,2.71,2.71,0,0,0-.26-1.24,2.06,2.06,0,0,0-.72-.8,3.35,3.35,0,0,0-1.09-.42,7.2,7.2,0,0,0-1.37-.12h-5v3.88h0v1.27h0v5.86h1.3V312.5H542l3.09,5.88h1.5l-3.21-5.9A2.41,2.41,0,0,0,544.19,312.25Zm-2.16-1h-3.77v-2.63H542a3.47,3.47,0,0,1,1.67.3,1.07,1.07,0,0,1,.47,1,1.46,1.46,0,0,1-.14.68.8.8,0,0,1-.37.38,1.85,1.85,0,0,1-.65.19A6.41,6.41,0,0,1,542,311.27Zm6.49,7.11h1.3v-11h-1.3Zm7.29-7.14a1.5,1.5,0,0,1-.46-.09A1.17,1.17,0,0,1,555,311l-.11-.08-.93.85.12.12a1.93,1.93,0,0,0,.7.44c.16,0,.31.1.45.13l-3.09,6h1.52l3-5.86h2.71l2.86,5.77.05.09h1.46l-5.73-11.23Zm2.89,0h-1.49l.75-1.47ZM575.06,313a3.7,3.7,0,0,0-.53-.78,2.63,2.63,0,0,0-.56-.49,2,2,0,0,0,.5-.71,2.89,2.89,0,0,0,.2-1.06,2.58,2.58,0,0,0-.29-1.32,2.11,2.11,0,0,0-.78-.79,3,3,0,0,0-1.11-.38,8.59,8.59,0,0,0-1.26-.09h-5v11h6.17a2.46,2.46,0,0,0,1.3-.37,3.66,3.66,0,0,0,1-.91,4.38,4.38,0,0,0,.6-1.18,3.89,3.89,0,0,0,.21-1.2,4.24,4.24,0,0,0-.09-.85A3.76,3.76,0,0,0,575.06,313Zm-7.55-4.36h3.72a3.49,3.49,0,0,1,1.68.3,1.06,1.06,0,0,1,.46,1,1.47,1.47,0,0,1-.13.68.9.9,0,0,1-.37.38,1.85,1.85,0,0,1-.65.19,6.55,6.55,0,0,1-.94.06h-3.77Zm6.53,6.82a3,3,0,0,1-.36.79,2.41,2.41,0,0,1-.57.62,1.12,1.12,0,0,1-.73.25h-4.87v-4.59h4.87a1.44,1.44,0,0,1,.82.22,1.76,1.76,0,0,1,.56.56,2.7,2.7,0,0,1,.31.72,3,3,0,0,1,.09.69A2.76,2.76,0,0,1,574,315.46Zm4.9-8.08h-1.3v11h8.29v-1.26h-7Zm10.62,9.74v-4.59h5.92v-1.26h-5.92v-2.63h6.86v-1.26h-8.16v3.88a2,2,0,0,1-.4-.09,1.5,1.5,0,0,1-.38-.19l-.1-.09-.94.86.13.12a1.93,1.93,0,0,0,.57.37,3.56,3.56,0,0,0,.58.19,2.56,2.56,0,0,0,.47.08h.07v5.86h8.3v-1.26Z" transform="translate(-132.83 -11.12)"/>
        <path class="cls-41" d="M491.22,246.16l-1.73,3,11.34,18.56.12.19-2.3,0a4.29,4.29,0,0,1-2.07-.3,3.19,3.19,0,0,1-1-.78l-2.26,4.28a3.43,3.43,0,0,0,2.11,1c1.14.07,3.13,0,3.18,0l4.91-.05,1,1.68-.75,1.29L495,290.36l17,0-2.45-4.26-6.09.07,4.08-7.47,9.87,16.13-25,0-1.79,3.1h32.28Zm8.09,29.16-5,0-5.5,9.7-3.6-5.71,9-16.09-2.73-4.38L481.91,276l-2.28-4,9.7-16.65-1.81-2.92-26.44,45.36h2.78l17.63,0h5.32l3.66-6.6Zm-16.09,19.5H466.38l10.5-18,1.62,2.55-6.58,11h5.89l4.35-7.36,3.85,6.93Z" transform="translate(-132.83 -11.12)"/>
        <g>
          <path class="cls-41" d="M394.4,328.68V328h4.42v.71H397v4.76h-.78v-4.76Z" transform="translate(-132.83 -11.12)"/>
          <path class="cls-41" d="M405.16,328h.77v5.47h-.77v-2.1h-2.93v2.1h-.78V328h.78v2.66h2.93Z" transform="translate(-132.83 -11.12)"/>
          <path class="cls-41" d="M412.4,332.73v.71h-3.6V328h3.6v.71h-2.82v1.73h2.61v.71h-2.61v1.61Z" transform="translate(-132.83 -11.12)"/>
          <path class="cls-41" d="M422.35,328h.78v5.47h-.78l-3.19-4.21v4.21h-.78V328h.79l3.18,4.19Z" transform="translate(-132.83 -11.12)"/>
          <path class="cls-41" d="M429.59,332.73v.71H426V328h3.59v.71h-2.82v1.73h2.61v.71h-2.61v1.61Z" transform="translate(-132.83 -11.12)"/>
          <path class="cls-41" d="M437.43,332.64l1.2-4.67h.8l-1.4,5.47h-1.19l-1.17-4.06-1.17,4.06h-1.2L431.91,328h.8l1.2,4.67,1.36-4.67h.79Z" transform="translate(-132.83 -11.12)"/>
          <path class="cls-41" d="M444.92,332.61l.55-.45a2.28,2.28,0,0,0,1.57.67c1,0,1.19-.65,1.19-.81,0-1.13-3.2-.68-3.2-2.72,0-.5.35-1.43,1.85-1.43a2.19,2.19,0,0,1,1.87.82l-.54.4a2,2,0,0,0-1.39-.51c-.52,0-1,.26-1,.79,0,1.38,3.21.76,3.21,2.72,0,.51-.48,1.45-2,1.45A2.41,2.41,0,0,1,444.92,332.61Z" transform="translate(-132.83 -11.12)"/>
          <path class="cls-41" d="M451.08,328.68V328h4.42v.71h-1.82v4.76h-.78v-4.76Z" transform="translate(-132.83 -11.12)"/>
          <path class="cls-41" d="M460,328l2.09,5.47h-.84l-.39-1H458l-.4,1h-.83l2.09-5.47Zm-1.69,3.72h2.27l-1.13-3Z" transform="translate(-132.83 -11.12)"/>
          <path class="cls-41" d="M468.51,328h.77v5.47h-.78l-3.19-4.21v4.21h-.77V328h.78l3.19,4.19Z" transform="translate(-132.83 -11.12)"/>
          <path class="cls-41" d="M474.22,333.44h-2.07V328h2.07a2.74,2.74,0,0,1,0,5.47Zm-1.29-4.76v4.05h1.33a2,2,0,0,0,0-4.05Z" transform="translate(-132.83 -11.12)"/>
          <path class="cls-41" d="M482,328l2.09,5.47h-.83l-.4-1h-2.82l-.39,1h-.83l2.08-5.47Zm-1.69,3.72h2.28l-1.14-3Z" transform="translate(-132.83 -11.12)"/>
          <path class="cls-41" d="M489.3,331.69l1.36,1.75h-.89l-1.32-1.68h-1.1v1.68h-.78V328h2.11a1.81,1.81,0,0,1,2,1.89A1.7,1.7,0,0,1,489.3,331.69Zm-1.95-.64h1.35a1.19,1.19,0,0,0,0-2.37h-1.35Z" transform="translate(-132.83 -11.12)"/>
          <path class="cls-41" d="M495.2,333.44h-2.07V328h2.07a2.74,2.74,0,0,1,0,5.47Zm-1.29-4.76v4.05h1.33a2,2,0,0,0,0-4.05Z" transform="translate(-132.83 -11.12)"/>
          <path class="cls-41" d="M503.84,328h.78v5.47h-.78Z" transform="translate(-132.83 -11.12)"/>
          <path class="cls-41" d="M511.46,328h.78v5.47h-.79l-3.18-4.21v4.21h-.78V328h.79l3.18,4.19Z" transform="translate(-132.83 -11.12)"/>
          <path class="cls-41" d="M518.38,328h.77v5.47h-.77Z" transform="translate(-132.83 -11.12)"/>
          <path class="cls-41" d="M526,328h.78v5.47H526l-3.18-4.21v4.21H522V328h.79l3.18,4.19Z" transform="translate(-132.83 -11.12)"/>
          <path class="cls-41" d="M533.61,328h.77v5.47h-.78l-3.19-4.21v4.21h-.77V328h.78l3.19,4.19Z" transform="translate(-132.83 -11.12)"/>
          <path class="cls-41" d="M542.94,330.71a2.89,2.89,0,1,1-2.89-2.84A2.85,2.85,0,0,1,542.94,330.71Zm-.77,0a2.12,2.12,0,1,0-4.24,0,2.12,2.12,0,1,0,4.24,0Z" transform="translate(-132.83 -11.12)"/>
          <path class="cls-41" d="M546.94,333.44,544.85,328h.83l1.81,4.72,1.8-4.72h.83L548,333.44Z" transform="translate(-132.83 -11.12)"/>
          <path class="cls-41" d="M554.54,328l2.08,5.47h-.83l-.39-1h-2.82l-.4,1h-.83l2.09-5.47Zm-1.7,3.72h2.28l-1.13-3Z" transform="translate(-132.83 -11.12)"/>
          <path class="cls-41" d="M557.92,328.68V328h4.42v.71h-1.82v4.76h-.78v-4.76Z" transform="translate(-132.83 -11.12)"/>
          <path class="cls-41" d="M565,328h.78v5.47H565Z" transform="translate(-132.83 -11.12)"/>
          <path class="cls-41" d="M574.31,330.71a2.89,2.89,0,1,1-2.89-2.84A2.85,2.85,0,0,1,574.31,330.71Zm-.77,0a2.12,2.12,0,1,0-4.24,0,2.12,2.12,0,0,0,4.24,0Z" transform="translate(-132.83 -11.12)"/>
          <path class="cls-41" d="M581.06,328h.77v5.47h-.78l-3.19-4.21v4.21h-.77V328h.78l3.19,4.19Z" transform="translate(-132.83 -11.12)"/>
          <path class="cls-41" d="M584.7,328.52V328h1.83v.55h-.65v1.65h-.51v-1.65Zm2.81.3v1.35H587V328h.52l.79,1,.8-1h.52v2.2h-.52v-1.35l-.8.89Z" transform="translate(-132.83 -11.12)"/>
        </g>
      </g>
   
      <text class="cls-42" transform="translate(225.49 390.18)">A mac<tspan class="cls-43" x="44.3" y="0">r</tspan><tspan x="50.42" y="0">o lens </tspan><tspan class="cls-44" x="94.11" y="0">f</tspan><tspan x="100.24" y="0">or ope</tspan><tspan class="cls-45" x="146.33" y="0">r</tspan><tspan class="cls-46" x="152.44" y="0">ational success:</tspan><tspan x="16.03" y="20">App</tspan><tspan class="cls-43" x="45.55" y="20">r</tspan><tspan x="51.67" y="20">oach built to enable clari</tspan><tspan class="cls-47" x="230.95" y="20">t</tspan><tspan x="237.5" y="20">y,</tspan><tspan x="24.92" y="39.99">less risk, consistent e</tspan><tspan class="cls-48" x="174.96" y="39.99">x</tspan><tspan class="cls-49" x="182.49" y="39.99">ecution,</tspan><tspan x="38.09" y="59.98">st</tspan><tspan class="cls-43" x="51.32" y="59.98">r</tspan><tspan x="57.43" y="59.98">ategic </tspan><tspan class="cls-44" x="107.67" y="59.98">f</tspan><tspan class="cls-50" x="113.8" y="59.98">ocus, flexibili</tspan><tspan class="cls-51" x="208.89" y="59.98">t</tspan><tspan class="cls-49" x="215.44" y="59.98">y,</tspan><tspan x="73.18" y="79.98">&amp; optimal </tspan><tspan class="cls-45" x="146.43" y="79.98">r</tspan><tspan x="152.54" y="79.98">esults</tspan></text>
  <g></g>   
    </g>
</svg>
```

Answer (score 0):

The click events are not fired for elements with `display:none`.

Instead, you may switch opacity to 0.

Demo in the snipped below.

P.S. A very low opacity (e.g. 0.03) might be a good alternative to 0, since the outline of the hexagon will remain visible, hinting user about the clickable surface.

```js
function changeItem(element){
    var element  = document.getElementById(element).children;

    if(element[0].style.opacity == 0){
        for (var i = 0; i < element.length - 1; i++) {
             element[i].style.opacity = 1  }
    }else{
        for (var i = 0; i < element.length - 1; i++) {
    element[i].style.opacity = 0
  }
    }
}
```

```css
.cls-1 {
        isolation: isolate;
      }
      .cls-2 {
        fill: #3ab694;
      }

      .cls-3 {
        font-size: 22.22px;
      }

      .cls-10, .cls-3 {
        fill: blue;
      }

      .cls-3, .cls-35, .cls-42 {
        font-family: Grold-Medium, Grold;
        font-weight: 500;
      }

      .cls-4 {
        letter-spacing: -0.01em;
      }

      .cls-5 {
        letter-spacing: 0em;
      }

      .cls-6 {
        letter-spacing: -0.07em;
      }

      .cls-7 {
        letter-spacing: -0.01em;
      }

      .cls-8 {
        letter-spacing: -0.01em;
      }

      .cls-9 {
        fill: #62c08c;
      }

      .cls-15, .cls-29, .cls-33, .cls-9 {
        opacity: 0.5;
      }

      .cls-15, .cls-20, .cls-26, .cls-29, .cls-33, .cls-9 {
        mix-blend-mode: multiply;
      }

      .cls-11, .cls-16, .cls-21, .cls-27, .cls-30, .cls-34 {
        opacity: 0.15;
        mix-blend-mode: overlay;
      }

      .cls-11 {
        fill: url(#White_Black_2);
      }

      .cls-12 {
        fill: #0bb1d2;
      }

      .cls-13 {
        letter-spacing: -0.01em;
      }

      .cls-14 {
        letter-spacing: -0.03em;
      }

      .cls-15 {
        fill: #2fb2cb;
      }

      .cls-16 {
        fill: url(#White_Black_2-2);
      }

      .cls-17 {
        fill: #223f70;
      }

      .cls-18 {
        letter-spacing: -0.01em;
      }

      .cls-19 {
        letter-spacing: -0.02em;
      }

      .cls-20 {
        fill: #0d70a6;
      }

      .cls-20, .cls-26 {
        opacity: 0.45;
      }

      .cls-21 {
        fill: url(#White_Black_2-3);
      }

      .cls-22 {
        fill: #226869;
      }
      .cls-23 {
        letter-spacing: -0.02em;
      }

      .cls-24 {
        letter-spacing: 0em;
      }

      .cls-25 {
        letter-spacing: -0.01em;
      }

      .cls-26 {
        fill: #ac2752;
      }

      .cls-27 {
        fill: url(#White_Black_2-4);
      }

      .cls-28 {
        fill: #eca825;
      }

      .cls-29 {
        fill: #e8584b;
      }

      .cls-30 {
        fill: url(#White_Black_2-5);
      }

      .cls-31 {
        fill: #543a71;
      }

      .cls-32 {
        letter-spacing: -0.03em;
      }

      .cls-33 {
        fill: #fec24e;
      }

      .cls-34 {
        fill: url(#White_Black_2-6);
      }

      .cls-35 {
        font-size: 36.1px;
      }

      .cls-35, .cls-42 {
        fill: #231f20;
      }

      .cls-36 {
        letter-spacing: -0.05em;
      }

      .cls-37 {
        letter-spacing: -0.09em;
      }

      .cls-38 {
        letter-spacing: -0.1em;
      }

      .cls-39 {
        letter-spacing: -0.02em;
      }

      .cls-40 {
        letter-spacing: -0.01em;
      }

      .cls-41 {
        fill: #100b0b;
      }

      .cls-42 {
        font-size: 16.66px;
      }

      .cls-43 {
        letter-spacing: -0.01em;
      }

      .cls-44 {
        letter-spacing: -0.01em;
      }

      .cls-45 {
        letter-spacing: -0.01em;
      }

      .cls-46 {
        letter-spacing: 0em;
      }

      .cls-47 {
        letter-spacing: 0.02em;
      }

      .cls-48 {
        letter-spacing: -0.02em;
      }

      .cls-49 {
        letter-spacing: 0em;
      }

      .cls-50 {
        letter-spacing: 0em;
      }

      .cls-51 {
        letter-spacing: 0.02em;
      }
```

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" 
     xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"  
     width="960px" 
     height="560px" 
     viewBox="0 0 960px 560px">
 <defs>

      <linearGradient id="White_Black_2" data-name="White, Black 2" x1="303.54" y1="51.04" x2="476.73" y2="224.23" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
        <stop offset="0" stop-color="#fff"/>
        <stop offset="1" stop-color="#010101"/>
      </linearGradient>
      <linearGradient id="White_Black_2-2" x1="108.25" y1="250.7" x2="381.22" y2="523.68" xlink:href="#White_Black_2"/>
      <linearGradient id="White_Black_2-3" x1="250.27" y1="417.78" x2="496.01" y2="663.52" xlink:href="#White_Black_2"/>
      <linearGradient id="White_Black_2-4" x1="508.24" y1="517.37" x2="681.43" y2="690.55" xlink:href="#White_Black_2"/>
      <linearGradient id="White_Black_2-5" x1="603.75" y1="217.92" x2="876.72" y2="490.89" xlink:href="#White_Black_2"/>
      <linearGradient id="White_Black_2-6" x1="488.96" y1="78.08" x2="734.7" y2="323.82" xlink:href="#White_Black_2"/>
    </defs>
 <g id="Middle_Info" onclick="changeItem('Middle_Info')" data-name="Middle Info">
      <polygon class="cls-10" points="438.48 490.62 285.48 492.54 207.32 360.99 282.17 227.53 435.17 225.62 513.32 357.17 438.48 490.62"/>
      <text class="cls-35" transform="translate(223.6 362.5)">INN<tspan class="cls-36" x="54.62" y="0">O</tspan><tspan class="cls-37" x="78.88" y="0">V</tspan><tspan class="cls-38" x="97.73" y="0">A</tspan><tspan x="116.21" y="0">TION </tspan><tspan class="cls-39" x="200.62" y="0">3</tspan><tspan class="cls-40" x="217.73" y="0">6</tspan><tspan x="235.99" y="0">0°</tspan></text>
      <g>
        <path class="cls-41" d="M387.46,318.38h1.3v-11h-1.3Zm11.88-2.85-7.9-8.63v11.48h1.3V310.1l7.9,8.7V307.38h-1.3Zm12.8-6.53a5.91,5.91,0,0,0-1.82-1.19,5.84,5.84,0,0,0-2.21-.43h-3.56a1.77,1.77,0,0,1-.57-.1,1.5,1.5,0,0,1-.38-.19l-.11-.08-.93.86.13.12a2.23,2.23,0,0,0,.56.36,3.91,3.91,0,0,0,.58.19,2.79,2.79,0,0,0,.48.09h.07v0h1.3v0h2.43a4.46,4.46,0,0,1,1.71.34,4.57,4.57,0,0,1,1.4.91,4.33,4.33,0,0,1,.95,1.36,4,4,0,0,1,0,3.29,4.25,4.25,0,0,1-.95,1.34,4.57,4.57,0,0,1-1.4.91,4.45,4.45,0,0,1-1.71.33h-2.43v-7.25h-1.3v8.51h3.73a5.84,5.84,0,0,0,2.21-.43,6.07,6.07,0,0,0,1.82-1.18,5.66,5.66,0,0,0,1.23-1.74,5.2,5.2,0,0,0,.45-2.14,5.13,5.13,0,0,0-.45-2.14A5.59,5.59,0,0,0,412.14,309Zm6,3.53H424v-1.26h-5.92v-2.63H425v-1.26h-8.16v3.88a2.09,2.09,0,0,1-.41-.09A1.42,1.42,0,0,1,416,311l-.11-.09-.94.86.14.12a2,2,0,0,0,.56.37,3.91,3.91,0,0,0,.58.19,2.65,2.65,0,0,0,.48.08h.07v5.86h8.29v-1.26h-7Zm16.9-4.61a3.7,3.7,0,0,0-1.1-.42,6.23,6.23,0,0,0-1.22-.12h-5v11H429V312.5h3.78a5.91,5.91,0,0,0,1.59-.19,2.77,2.77,0,0,0,1-.55,2,2,0,0,0,.58-.83,2.83,2.83,0,0,0,.17-1,2.39,2.39,0,0,0-.31-1.25A2.45,2.45,0,0,0,435,307.92Zm-.32,2.72a.8.8,0,0,1-.37.38,1.85,1.85,0,0,1-.65.19,6.41,6.41,0,0,1-.93.06H429v-2.63h3.72a3.47,3.47,0,0,1,1.67.3,1.05,1.05,0,0,1,.47,1A1.46,1.46,0,0,1,434.7,310.64Zm5.08,1.89h5.92v-1.26h-5.92v-2.63h6.86v-1.26h-8.16v3.88a2,2,0,0,1-.4-.09,1.5,1.5,0,0,1-.38-.19l-.1-.09-.94.86.13.12a1.93,1.93,0,0,0,.57.37,3.56,3.56,0,0,0,.58.19,2.43,2.43,0,0,0,.47.08h.07v5.86h8.3v-1.26h-7Zm16.42,3-7.9-8.63v11.48h1.3V310.1l7.9,8.7V307.38h-1.3ZM469,309a5.91,5.91,0,0,0-1.82-1.19,5.84,5.84,0,0,0-2.21-.43h-3.56a1.77,1.77,0,0,1-.57-.1,1.35,1.35,0,0,1-.38-.19l-.11-.08-.94.86.14.12a2.23,2.23,0,0,0,.56.36,3.91,3.91,0,0,0,.58.19,2.79,2.79,0,0,0,.48.09h.07v0h1.3v0H465a4.5,4.5,0,0,1,1.71.34,4.57,4.57,0,0,1,1.4.91,4.33,4.33,0,0,1,.95,1.36,4,4,0,0,1,0,3.29,4.25,4.25,0,0,1-.95,1.34,4.57,4.57,0,0,1-1.4.91,4.45,4.45,0,0,1-1.71.33h-2.43v-7.25h-1.3v8.51H465a5.84,5.84,0,0,0,2.21-.43,5.9,5.9,0,0,0,1.81-1.18,5.35,5.35,0,0,0,1.23-1.74,5.21,5.21,0,0,0,.46-2.14,5.14,5.14,0,0,0-.46-2.14A5.41,5.41,0,0,0,469,309Zm6,3.53h5.91v-1.26H475v-2.63h6.86v-1.26h-8.16v3.88a2.09,2.09,0,0,1-.41-.09,1.42,1.42,0,0,1-.37-.19l-.11-.09-.94.86.13.12a1.93,1.93,0,0,0,.57.37,3.91,3.91,0,0,0,.58.19,2.65,2.65,0,0,0,.48.08h.07v5.86H482v-1.26h-7Zm16.41,3-7.9-8.63v11.48h1.3V310.1l7.9,8.7V307.38h-1.3Zm3.15-6.89h4v9.74h1.3v-9.74h3.94v-1.26h-9.2Zm28.7-1.26-4.34,8.24-4.29-8.15-.05-.09h-1.44l5.78,11.23,5.76-11.23Zm3.31,3.86a1.5,1.5,0,0,1-.45-.09,1.23,1.23,0,0,1-.38-.19l-.11-.08-.93.85.12.12a2,2,0,0,0,.7.44c.16,0,.31.1.45.13l-3.08,6h1.51l3-5.86H530l2.87,5.77,0,.09h1.46l-5.73-11.23Zm2.89,0H528l.74-1.47Zm14.75,1a2.17,2.17,0,0,0,.72-.61,2.34,2.34,0,0,0,.39-.81,3.26,3.26,0,0,0,.12-.87,2.71,2.71,0,0,0-.26-1.24,2.06,2.06,0,0,0-.72-.8,3.35,3.35,0,0,0-1.09-.42,7.2,7.2,0,0,0-1.37-.12h-5v3.88h0v1.27h0v5.86h1.3V312.5H542l3.09,5.88h1.5l-3.21-5.9A2.41,2.41,0,0,0,544.19,312.25Zm-2.16-1h-3.77v-2.63H542a3.47,3.47,0,0,1,1.67.3,1.07,1.07,0,0,1,.47,1,1.46,1.46,0,0,1-.14.68.8.8,0,0,1-.37.38,1.85,1.85,0,0,1-.65.19A6.41,6.41,0,0,1,542,311.27Zm6.49,7.11h1.3v-11h-1.3Zm7.29-7.14a1.5,1.5,0,0,1-.46-.09A1.17,1.17,0,0,1,555,311l-.11-.08-.93.85.12.12a1.93,1.93,0,0,0,.7.44c.16,0,.31.1.45.13l-3.09,6h1.52l3-5.86h2.71l2.86,5.77.05.09h1.46l-5.73-11.23Zm2.89,0h-1.49l.75-1.47ZM575.06,313a3.7,3.7,0,0,0-.53-.78,2.63,2.63,0,0,0-.56-.49,2,2,0,0,0,.5-.71,2.89,2.89,0,0,0,.2-1.06,2.58,2.58,0,0,0-.29-1.32,2.11,2.11,0,0,0-.78-.79,3,3,0,0,0-1.11-.38,8.59,8.59,0,0,0-1.26-.09h-5v11h6.17a2.46,2.46,0,0,0,1.3-.37,3.66,3.66,0,0,0,1-.91,4.38,4.38,0,0,0,.6-1.18,3.89,3.89,0,0,0,.21-1.2,4.24,4.24,0,0,0-.09-.85A3.76,3.76,0,0,0,575.06,313Zm-7.55-4.36h3.72a3.49,3.49,0,0,1,1.68.3,1.06,1.06,0,0,1,.46,1,1.47,1.47,0,0,1-.13.68.9.9,0,0,1-.37.38,1.85,1.85,0,0,1-.65.19,6.55,6.55,0,0,1-.94.06h-3.77Zm6.53,6.82a3,3,0,0,1-.36.79,2.41,2.41,0,0,1-.57.62,1.12,1.12,0,0,1-.73.25h-4.87v-4.59h4.87a1.44,1.44,0,0,1,.82.22,1.76,1.76,0,0,1,.56.56,2.7,2.7,0,0,1,.31.72,3,3,0,0,1,.09.69A2.76,2.76,0,0,1,574,315.46Zm4.9-8.08h-1.3v11h8.29v-1.26h-7Zm10.62,9.74v-4.59h5.92v-1.26h-5.92v-2.63h6.86v-1.26h-8.16v3.88a2,2,0,0,1-.4-.09,1.5,1.5,0,0,1-.38-.19l-.1-.09-.94.86.13.12a1.93,1.93,0,0,0,.57.37,3.56,3.56,0,0,0,.58.19,2.56,2.56,0,0,0,.47.08h.07v5.86h8.3v-1.26Z" transform="translate(-132.83 -11.12)"/>
        <path class="cls-41" d="M491.22,246.16l-1.73,3,11.34,18.56.12.19-2.3,0a4.29,4.29,0,0,1-2.07-.3,3.19,3.19,0,0,1-1-.78l-2.26,4.28a3.43,3.43,0,0,0,2.11,1c1.14.07,3.13,0,3.18,0l4.91-.05,1,1.68-.75,1.29L495,290.36l17,0-2.45-4.26-6.09.07,4.08-7.47,9.87,16.13-25,0-1.79,3.1h32.28Zm8.09,29.16-5,0-5.5,9.7-3.6-5.71,9-16.09-2.73-4.38L481.91,276l-2.28-4,9.7-16.65-1.81-2.92-26.44,45.36h2.78l17.63,0h5.32l3.66-6.6Zm-16.09,19.5H466.38l10.5-18,1.62,2.55-6.58,11h5.89l4.35-7.36,3.85,6.93Z" transform="translate(-132.83 -11.12)"/>
        <g>
          <path class="cls-41" d="M394.4,328.68V328h4.42v.71H397v4.76h-.78v-4.76Z" transform="translate(-132.83 -11.12)"/>
          <path class="cls-41" d="M405.16,328h.77v5.47h-.77v-2.1h-2.93v2.1h-.78V328h.78v2.66h2.93Z" transform="translate(-132.83 -11.12)"/>
          <path class="cls-41" d="M412.4,332.73v.71h-3.6V328h3.6v.71h-2.82v1.73h2.61v.71h-2.61v1.61Z" transform="translate(-132.83 -11.12)"/>
          <path class="cls-41" d="M422.35,328h.78v5.47h-.78l-3.19-4.21v4.21h-.78V328h.79l3.18,4.19Z" transform="translate(-132.83 -11.12)"/>
          <path class="cls-41" d="M429.59,332.73v.71H426V328h3.59v.71h-2.82v1.73h2.61v.71h-2.61v1.61Z" transform="translate(-132.83 -11.12)"/>
          <path class="cls-41" d="M437.43,332.64l1.2-4.67h.8l-1.4,5.47h-1.19l-1.17-4.06-1.17,4.06h-1.2L431.91,328h.8l1.2,4.67,1.36-4.67h.79Z" transform="translate(-132.83 -11.12)"/>
          <path class="cls-41" d="M444.92,332.61l.55-.45a2.28,2.28,0,0,0,1.57.67c1,0,1.19-.65,1.19-.81,0-1.13-3.2-.68-3.2-2.72,0-.5.35-1.43,1.85-1.43a2.19,2.19,0,0,1,1.87.82l-.54.4a2,2,0,0,0-1.39-.51c-.52,0-1,.26-1,.79,0,1.38,3.21.76,3.21,2.72,0,.51-.48,1.45-2,1.45A2.41,2.41,0,0,1,444.92,332.61Z" transform="translate(-132.83 -11.12)"/>
          <path class="cls-41" d="M451.08,328.68V328h4.42v.71h-1.82v4.76h-.78v-4.76Z" transform="translate(-132.83 -11.12)"/>
          <path class="cls-41" d="M460,328l2.09,5.47h-.84l-.39-1H458l-.4,1h-.83l2.09-5.47Zm-1.69,3.72h2.27l-1.13-3Z" transform="translate(-132.83 -11.12)"/>
          <path class="cls-41" d="M468.51,328h.77v5.47h-.78l-3.19-4.21v4.21h-.77V328h.78l3.19,4.19Z" transform="translate(-132.83 -11.12)"/>
          <path class="cls-41" d="M474.22,333.44h-2.07V328h2.07a2.74,2.74,0,0,1,0,5.47Zm-1.29-4.76v4.05h1.33a2,2,0,0,0,0-4.05Z" transform="translate(-132.83 -11.12)"/>
          <path class="cls-41" d="M482,328l2.09,5.47h-.83l-.4-1h-2.82l-.39,1h-.83l2.08-5.47Zm-1.69,3.72h2.28l-1.14-3Z" transform="translate(-132.83 -11.12)"/>
          <path class="cls-41" d="M489.3,331.69l1.36,1.75h-.89l-1.32-1.68h-1.1v1.68h-.78V328h2.11a1.81,1.81,0,0,1,2,1.89A1.7,1.7,0,0,1,489.3,331.69Zm-1.95-.64h1.35a1.19,1.19,0,0,0,0-2.37h-1.35Z" transform="translate(-132.83 -11.12)"/>
          <path class="cls-41" d="M495.2,333.44h-2.07V328h2.07a2.74,2.74,0,0,1,0,5.47Zm-1.29-4.76v4.05h1.33a2,2,0,0,0,0-4.05Z" transform="translate(-132.83 -11.12)"/>
          <path class="cls-41" d="M503.84,328h.78v5.47h-.78Z" transform="translate(-132.83 -11.12)"/>
          <path class="cls-41" d="M511.46,328h.78v5.47h-.79l-3.18-4.21v4.21h-.78V328h.79l3.18,4.19Z" transform="translate(-132.83 -11.12)"/>
          <path class="cls-41" d="M518.38,328h.77v5.47h-.77Z" transform="translate(-132.83 -11.12)"/>
          <path class="cls-41" d="M526,328h.78v5.47H526l-3.18-4.21v4.21H522V328h.79l3.18,4.19Z" transform="translate(-132.83 -11.12)"/>
          <path class="cls-41" d="M533.61,328h.77v5.47h-.78l-3.19-4.21v4.21h-.77V328h.78l3.19,4.19Z" transform="translate(-132.83 -11.12)"/>
          <path class="cls-41" d="M542.94,330.71a2.89,2.89,0,1,1-2.89-2.84A2.85,2.85,0,0,1,542.94,330.71Zm-.77,0a2.12,2.12,0,1,0-4.24,0,2.12,2.12,0,1,0,4.24,0Z" transform="translate(-132.83 -11.12)"/>
          <path class="cls-41" d="M546.94,333.44,544.85,328h.83l1.81,4.72,1.8-4.72h.83L548,333.44Z" transform="translate(-132.83 -11.12)"/>
          <path class="cls-41" d="M554.54,328l2.08,5.47h-.83l-.39-1h-2.82l-.4,1h-.83l2.09-5.47Zm-1.7,3.72h2.28l-1.13-3Z" transform="translate(-132.83 -11.12)"/>
          <path class="cls-41" d="M557.92,328.68V328h4.42v.71h-1.82v4.76h-.78v-4.76Z" transform="translate(-132.83 -11.12)"/>
          <path class="cls-41" d="M565,328h.78v5.47H565Z" transform="translate(-132.83 -11.12)"/>
          <path class="cls-41" d="M574.31,330.71a2.89,2.89,0,1,1-2.89-2.84A2.85,2.85,0,0,1,574.31,330.71Zm-.77,0a2.12,2.12,0,1,0-4.24,0,2.12,2.12,0,0,0,4.24,0Z" transform="translate(-132.83 -11.12)"/>
          <path class="cls-41" d="M581.06,328h.77v5.47h-.78l-3.19-4.21v4.21h-.77V328h.78l3.19,4.19Z" transform="translate(-132.83 -11.12)"/>
          <path class="cls-41" d="M584.7,328.52V328h1.83v.55h-.65v1.65h-.51v-1.65Zm2.81.3v1.35H587V328h.52l.79,1,.8-1h.52v2.2h-.52v-1.35l-.8.89Z" transform="translate(-132.83 -11.12)"/>
        </g>
      </g>
   
      <text class="cls-42" transform="translate(225.49 390.18)">A mac<tspan class="cls-43" x="44.3" y="0">r</tspan><tspan x="50.42" y="0">o lens </tspan><tspan class="cls-44" x="94.11" y="0">f</tspan><tspan x="100.24" y="0">or ope</tspan><tspan class="cls-45" x="146.33" y="0">r</tspan><tspan class="cls-46" x="152.44" y="0">ational success:</tspan><tspan x="16.03" y="20">App</tspan><tspan class="cls-43" x="45.55" y="20">r</tspan><tspan x="51.67" y="20">oach built to enable clari</tspan><tspan class="cls-47" x="230.95" y="20">t</tspan><tspan x="237.5" y="20">y,</tspan><tspan x="24.92" y="39.99">less risk, consistent e</tspan><tspan class="cls-48" x="174.96" y="39.99">x</tspan><tspan class="cls-49" x="182.49" y="39.99">ecution,</tspan><tspan x="38.09" y="59.98">st</tspan><tspan class="cls-43" x="51.32" y="59.98">r</tspan><tspan x="57.43" y="59.98">ategic </tspan><tspan class="cls-44" x="107.67" y="59.98">f</tspan><tspan class="cls-50" x="113.8" y="59.98">ocus, flexibili</tspan><tspan class="cls-51" x="208.89" y="59.98">t</tspan><tspan class="cls-49" x="215.44" y="59.98">y,</tspan><tspan x="73.18" y="79.98">&amp; optimal </tspan><tspan class="cls-45" x="146.43" y="79.98">r</tspan><tspan x="152.54" y="79.98">esults</tspan></text>
  <g></g>   
    </g>
</svg>
```

Comment: Thanks...  I would need to only apply this javascript to the "middle_info" item, referenced on line 256.   Is there a way to check the id --- something like: document.getElementById(element).id() == 'Middle_Info'  ?

Comment: The variable `element` passed in `changeItem` contains the id, you may check it here (`if (element === 'Middle_info')`, before the variable gets overriden.
A good practice would be not to reuse the same variable name for two different things.